# cloudflare best optimized setting for magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have cloudflare CDN for my magento, what are the best & recommended setting I should set to optimize the speed.

I see that there is cache everything option in page rules. do you recommend this and how should I set it ?

Comment: anyone can suggest something

Comment: so you still want answer?